# How to prove that the class of non-context-free languages isn't closed under intersection?

Tags: computability, context-free

I am not sure how to approach this. L1 and L2 are using the same alphabet.

Comment: Your question makes no sense, since you are using the terminology incorrectly. One cannot speak of "two languages not being closed under intersection" any more than one can speak of "two natural numbers not being closed under division". What one can speak of is the *class of context-free languages* not being closed under intersection. If the class *were* closed under intersection, then we would have that for any two context-free languages $L_1$ and $L_2$, $L_1 \cap L_2$ would be context-free as well. All you need to disprove this is to find a counterexample, that is, a suitable $L_1$ and $L_2.

Comment: @HansHüttel I just have difficulty to find such a counterexample.

Comment: Can you express a non-context-free language that you know as the intersection of two context-free languages?

Comment: This is [answered on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language#Nonclosure_under_intersection.2C_complement.2C_and_difference). Please do at least a little research before asking people to help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint. Let

$$
L_1=\{a^nb^nc^{2n}\mid n\ge 0\}\text{ and } L_2=\{a^nb^nc^{2n+1}\mid n\ge 0\}
$$

- Show that $L_1$ and $L_2$ are not context-free.
- Say something about $L_1\cap L_2$